# Match rows based on first field and combine second field

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I would like to combine entries from the second field from two files using awk, sed or similar.

File0:

```
string:data:moredata
```

File1:

```
string:random:moredata
```

If the first field, **string** in *file0* has a matching entry in *file1* then print

```
$random:$data
```

Selecting the fields seems trivial:

```
$ awk -F':' '{print $2}' filename
```

Need to match rows and print matching column $2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one -

```
awk -F":" 'NR==FNR {x[$1] = $0; y[$1] = $2; next} ($1 in x) {print $2":"y[$1]}' file1 file2
```

**Execution:**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat file1
string:data:moredata

[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat file2
string:random:moredata

[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk -F":" 'NR==FNR {x[$1] = $0; y[$1] = $2; next} ($1 in x) {print $2":"y[$1]}' file1 file2
random:data
```

In this solution, we are loading the whole record of file1 in to the array indexed at column 1. We do a quick check in the next file to see if the column 1 is present. If it is then print statement is executed.

**Negative Test:**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat file1
string:data:moredata
man:woman:child

[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat file2
man:random:moredata
string:woman:child

[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk -F":" 'NR==FNR {x[$1] = $0; y[$1] = $2; next} ($1 in x) {print $2":"y[$1]}' file1 file2
random:woman
woman:data
```

*Just to add to the explanation, NR and FNR are awk's in-built variables. NR gives line number and does not get reset to 0 when looped over two files. FNR on the contrary is also a line number that gets reset to 0 when second file starts. Thus this allows us to store the file 1 into the array because that action is only done when NR==FNR. As soon as this condition becomes false, it means the second file has started and next pattern action statement begins to execute.*

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` solution might work for you:

```
# cat file1
string0:data1:moredata
string2:data3:moredata
string4:data5:moredata
string6:data7:moredata
string8:data9:moredata
# cat file2
string0:random1:moredata
string2:random3:moredata
string4:random5:moredata
cat file1 - <<<"EOF" file2 | 
sed '1,/^EOF/{H;d};G;s/^\([^:]*:\)\([^:]*:\).*\1\([^:]*\).*/$\2$\3/p;d'
$random1:$data1
$random3:$data3
$random5:$data5
```

Explanation:

Concatenate the files with an `EOF` delimiter. Slurp the first file into the hold space (HS). Append the HS to all lines in the second file making a lookup table. Use grouping and backreferences to substitute the required output result. BTW were the `$`'s in `$random:$data` intended?

This solution might also be made more efficient by only retaining the necessary data in the lookup and each line of file2.

Comment: Nicely done! You should start writing an e-book on SED one-liners. I still haven't figured out G, H and other crazy stuff. :) +1

Comment: The `$` was not required, wanted to convey different fields. Thanks for the the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

`join - join lines of two files on a common field`

So do your awk thing, only print both the data and the "key" field. Then do a join command similar to: `join -1 1 -2 1 file1 file2 > joined.dat`

Comment: Not sure how to match the rows just using join as they have may not be sorted and furthermore **file0** may have fewer rows.

Comment: I don't think fewer rows matters at all. It's just like db tables, I assume. (I've only used `join` once and it was years ago.) The `man` page is unclear on sorting. One part says you have to sort, another implies that `join` can sort for you. Experimentation is called for, I guess.