# Perl: Match duplicate on first field combine last field

Tags: perl

See question here:
[match-rows-based-on-first-field-and-combine-second-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283235/match-rows-based-on-first-field-and-combine-second-field)

How would you tackle this in perl given the following conditions:

- A single CSV file
- There are several duplicate records that fall in different categories
- You need to match on first field and merge/append the category field

Sample file:

```
External ID     Item Name       Item Description        Release Date    Expiry Date     Weight  Template ID     Enabled EntityId        Classifications Address N/A     City    State   Zipcode Country of domain purchase is made from Title   Cover Image     Link    Author
411280  Shade me        Shade me        04-May-2017     01-Jan-9999             0       Y       -1      Teen                                                    Shade me        MC.GIF        http://catalog.org/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=411280 Brown, Jennifer
411280  Shade me        Shade me        04-May-2017     01-Jan-9999             0       Y       -1      Books                                                   Shade me        MC.GIF        http://catalog.org/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=411280 Brown, Jennifer
413036  Now that's what I call music!   Now that's what I call music!   04-May-2017     01-Jan-9999             0       Y       -1      Teen                                                    Now that's what I call music!  MC.GIF http://catalog.org/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=413036
```

The challenge is to match duplicate Ids and merge the categories.

```
Shade me        MC.GIF        http://catalog.org/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=411280 Brown, Jennifer
    411280  Shade me        Shade me        04-May-2017     01-Jan-9999             0       Y       -1      Teen;Books
```

**UPDATE**

```
while ( <FILE> ) { 
        next if 1..1;
        chomp $_; 

        my ( $id, $name, $desc, $reldate, $expdate, $weight, $temp, $enabled, $ent, $class, $addr, $na, $city, $state, $zip, $country, $title, $img, $link, $auth ) = split /\t/ , $_; 

        if ( ! $merge{$id} ) { 
                $merge{$id} = "$id, $name, $desc, $reldate, $expdate, $weight, $temp, $enabled, $ent, $class, $addr, $na, $city, $state, $zip, $country, $title, $img, $link, $auth";
        } else {
                $merge{$class} .= ";$class" if ( $merge{$id} ne $class )
        }
}

p %merge;
```

The line giving me issues is:

```
$merge{$class} .= ";$class" if ( $merge{$id} ne $class )
```

You can see what I need to do -- merge the class field. Not working

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the specific problem or error you're having? Where is the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Will post code. Actually -- nearly got it working.

Comment: Code posted. It is nearly working but not combining the class field.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your sample file.

Comment: I will update. Didn't want to complicate things.

Comment: "Not working" meaning...? You get an error message? You get an unexpected result? The code formats your drive?

Comment: In your sample file, your columns appear to be separated by spaces, but you're splitting on `\t`.

Comment: It's tab delimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would load the file into some data-structure and remember each unique column value, and then print them as you want. E.g. as in this example (using `|` as it is delimiter better visible as the `\t`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use 5.024;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $records;
my $numcols;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my(@cols) = split /\|/, $_, -1;
    $numcols = @cols if( $. == 1 );
    die "Wrong number of columns (@{[scalar @cols]} instead of $numcols) in line $." unless (@cols == $numcols);
    $records->{$cols[0]}->[0] = $. unless $records->{$cols[0]}; #remember the line# of the 1st apperance
    for(my $c = 1; $c < $numcols; $c++) {   #skip the id (col[0])
        $records->{$cols[0]}->[$c]->{$cols[$c]}++;
    }
}
# if want, check the data-structure
#say Dumper($records);

for my $id (sort {$records->{$a}->[0] <=> $records->{$b}->[0]} keys %$records) {
    say join("|",
            $id,
            map { join(';', sort grep {/\S/} keys $records->{$id}->[$_]->%*) } 1 .. $#{$records->{$id}}  #skip col[0]
        );
}

__DATA__
ID|Name1|Name2|Name3
id1|c11|c12|c13
id1|c11|c12|c13
id2|c21|c22|c23
id1|c31|c12|c13
id3|c41||c43
id1|c51|c12|c13
id1|c31||c13
id1|c11||c13
id1|c31|c12|c13
id2|c21|c22|c83
id4|c91|c92|
```

prints

```
ID|Name1|Name2|Name3
id1|c11;c31;c51|c12|c13
id2|c21|c22|c23;c83
id3|c41||c43
id4|c91|c92|
```

Using some shell for pretty columns `perl script.pl | sed 's/||/| |/g' | column -s'|' -t`

```
ID   Name1        Name2  Name3
id1  c11;c31;c51  c12    c13
id2  c21          c22    c23;c83
id3  c41                 c43
id4  c91          c92
```

Comment: I have 5.22 and I get errors `near "->%"`. Is there an equivalent for this?

Comment: It's line 25. Is there another way of writing this?

Comment: Got it! Used the following: `use feature qw(postderef say);`.

Comment: @Bubnoff it is possible to write also as `%{$records->{$id}->[$_]}`.

Answer (score -2):

A simple approach for small files could be done as above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use common::sense;    
use DDP;

my %merge;

while ( <DATA> )
{

 next if 1..1;

 chomp $_;

 my ( $id, $text, $category ) = split /,/ , $_;

 if ( ! $merge{$id} )
 {
     $merge{$id} = "$id,$text,$category";
 }
 else
 {
       my ( undef, undef , $c ) = split /,/ , $merge{$id};

       if ( $c !~ /\b$category\b/ )
       {
          $merge{$id} .= ";$category";
       }
 }


}

p %merge;

__DATA__
Id    Title               Category
12345,My favorite martian,aliens
13444,Texas Meat,BBQ
12345,My favorite martian,aliens
```

**Output:**

```
{
    12345   "12345,My favorite martian,aliens;space",
    13444   "13444,Texas Meat,BBQ"
}
```

Considering you don't want duplicate categories it would help.

Comment: if the 1st category will be `icecream` and the second `ice` it will not merge, because will match the substring.

Comment: @jm666 - what would you suggest? Exact match rather than REGEX? That would be `( $merge{$id} ne $category )` correct?

Comment: Just as @jm666 pointed, it will not merge, I edited my answer and now it might merge

Comment: Please use Text::CSV

Comment: @Robert I would but am unsure how to do what I need to do with it.

Comment: `Text::CSV` is nice if you've got to deal with linefeeding and quoting, but IMO not that worthwhile if not. `split /\t/` or similar works just as well in 95% of use cases.